# Insert into a Hive table with a special character in the partition

Tags: amazon-web-services, hive, hql

I have the following table created this way :

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `my_table`(
  `user_id` string COMMENT '', 
  `this_date` string COMMENT '')
  partitioned by (
    `version` string COMMENT '')
ROW FORMAT SERDE 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe' 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  's3://bucket/sub_bucket/sub_sub_bucket/table_folder'
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'parquet.compression'='SNAPPY')
```

And I would like to make an insert into query :

```
insert into my_talbe values ('1', '2018-12-01', "2019-01-01 12:33:47.456890")
```

But it fails.

I execute this query on Athena so the error doesn't say much but I'm sure that the : is the problem
So I tried the following

```
insert into my_talbe values ('1', '2018-12-01', "2019-01-01 12 33 47.456890")
```

And it works.

Is there a I could have the : in the partition folder ??
I need it to be compliant that has been created without using Athena (Hive).

Answer (score 1):

Both the insert statements seem to have missing partition part in them.

For a partitioned table `tab1` with a partition column and two other columns, the data should be inserted like the below,

`INSERT INTO tab1 partition ("abcdef") values (1, 2)`

So, the provided INSERT statement should throw an error like this

```
Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException 1:12 Need to specify partition columns because the destination table is partitioned. Error encountered near token 'my_table'
```

Also, answering to your original question - In Hadoop you cannot create files or directories those have the characters `/` or `:` as a part of its name.

So the better way of creating partition is to exclude these characters from the name.